# A text editor similar to Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: web-development, text-editor, ftp, wysiwyg

I am struggling to find a text editor that matches the features of Dreamweaver CS4, especially the brilliant FTP file tree it uses.

Can anyone recommend an editor or packages that will do:

- Code hinting (PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, maybe Typescript)
- FTP file tree (allowing local to FTP browsing in a file tree)
- Auto indent code into its correct format whilst writing
- Code highlighting (highlight any errors)
- WYSIWYG editor
- Git
- Autoprefixer
- Nice search and replace feature for large blocks of code

Comment: What do you mean by What You See Is What You Get? (WYSIWYG).
WYSIWYG is normally for things that are destined to be a visual medium.
Like print, or webpages.
Most text editors don't do this.
I have vague notion that Dreamweaver does have something along these lines, but I can't really recall much about it.

Is it different from a "Preview" plane?

Comment: Though mentioning *Dreamweaver* points at Windows: could you please explicitly mention what OS must be supported? Again guessing by "Dreamweaver": How much you are willing to pay?

Comment: @Izzy Adobe's Creative Suite (what CS stands for) and successors run on Windows and Mac.

Comment: Why don't you just upgrade to Dreamweaver CS6 or CC?

Comment: Thanks, @MattDMo – so we can't even "make an educated guess" on what OS the OP needs this for. As for the upgrade: Here we can guess, and my bet is money (subscription model; several companies I know of looking for replacements because of that).

Comment: @Izzy that's most likely true, I was just wondering. And you're right, now we have no idea of OS, either. Perhaps one of the Jetbrains products might work? They're cross-platform.